# Merge columns in MySQL SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores a default configuration and a table that stores a user configuration.  I can join the two tables and get all the info I need however I was hoping there might be a cleaner way to overwrite one column with the other when a value exists in the second column.

Example:

Current query result:

```
id  defaultValue   userValue
1       one           ONE
2       two
3       three        THREE
4       four
```

Desire query result:

```
id  value   
1   ONE
2   two
3   THREE
4   four
```

Maybe there isn't a good way to do this...  Thought I'd ask though as it's probably faster to do it in MySQL if a method exists than to do it in PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) for this:

```
SELECT id, COALESCE(uservalue,defaultvalue) AS value
FROM table
```